# Including a dependency in VS2010 - Visual Leak Detector

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include, memory-leak-detector

I'm trying to use [Visual Leak Detector 1.9h beta](http://sites.google.com/site/dmoulding/vld) in a Visual C++ project on Visual Studio 2010. When I build and run my project I get the following error:

> The program can't start because
>   vld.dll is missing from your computer.
>   Try reinstalling the program to fid
>   this problem.

The README that comes with VLD states for Visual C++ 8 and 9:

> Go to Tools ->
>   Options -> Projects and Solutions ->
>   VC++ Directories. Select "Include
>   files" from the "Show Directories For"
>   drop-down menu. Add the include
>   subdirectory from the Visual Leak
>   Detector installation directory. Move
>   it to the bottom of the list. Then
>   select "Library files" from the
>   drop-down menu and add the lib
>   subdirectory from the Visual Leak
>   Detector installation directory.
>   Again, move it to the bottom of the
>   list.

The menus suggested is deprecated in VS2010. **What would be the equivalent for VS2010?**

I tried the following without success:

- Right click on the project \ properties \ Configuration Properties \ C\C++ \ General \ Additional Include Directories -> add ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include"
- Right click on the project \ properties \ Configuration Properties \ Linker \ General \ Additional Library Directories -> add ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\vld.lib"

but as you can guess, it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got isn't fixable with any of the settings you're browsing through.  It is a straight-forward runtime error, Windows just cannot find the DLL that the tool needs.

First thing you need to do is find out where the installer put the vld.dll file.  You are clearly running a 64-bit operating system.  First look in c:\windows\system32, move it to c:\windows\syswow64 if you find it there so that 32-bit programs can find the DLL.  Also check if the installer messed with the system environment PATH variable (Control Panel + System, Advanced), you may have to restart Visual Studio to make the change effective.  Adding the install directory to this variable would be another solution. The last ditch make-it-work effort is to copy vld.dll into your build directory.

Comment: You are correct. The VLD installation placed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin" in the PATH environment variable (which is where the vld.dll resides). After I logged out and then in again it worked flawlessly. (maybe restarting VS2010 would have been enough, not sure)